# greasemonkey script won't work on FaceBook

Tags: javascript, facebook, greasemonkey

i have this code:

```
==UserScript==
// @name          name
// @namespace     url
// @description   desc
// @include       http://www.facebook.com/*
// @require       http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("a").click(function(){
        alert(1);
        return false;
    });

});
```

but when i install it, and click on some link i'm just taken to the adress, which means the script doesn't work.

can anyone tell me where's my mistake?

Comment: Have you tested your script for any other page? Narrow down the problem first.

Comment: yes, i tested it on another pages but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine and works for me on FF 4.0.1 with GM 0.9.2. You haven't specified the Firefox or GM version that you're working with - but I think I remember running into a problem where the external scripts would not get loaded. You might try copying and pasting the entire minified source of jQuery into your GM userscript, just after the header, before your code.

You might also want to make sure your code actually does get loaded by putting in some log/alert statements - I'd suggest `$().jquery` at least to ensure you have jQuery loaded and check it's version.

Comment: yeah, the problem was with the external script. i put the jquery min. source in my file and it worked. thanks